# Prove $Z[\sqrt{7}]$ is euclidean domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains, euclidean-domain

I am not able to prove it with euclidean evaluation $$ d(m+n\sqrt{7}) = |m^2 - 7 n^2 |$$. Is there any other way?

Comment: It is Euclidean with respect to this norm.

Comment: For the proof, compare with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215087/mathbbz-sqrt11-is-norm-euclidean?noredirect=1&lq=1), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124484/show-mathbbz-sqrt6-is-a-euclidean-domain?rq=1).

Comment: There is an OEIS related list https://oeis.org/A048981 , and the ring of integers in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 7)$ is Euclidean. References are inserted there.